# Uploading file local path: XXX remote path: XXX I/O Error: EOF

Tags: android, android-studio

On Android Studio 0.4.4, getting this error, even found this error in previous version too!

Uploading file local path:XXX/XXX.apk

remote path:/data/tmp/XXXX

I/O Error: EOF

Answer (score 3):

"Sync Project with Gradle Files" should solve the problem.

Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Answer (score 2):

The reason these errors tend to come up is because the Gradle file becomes out of sync. The way that I have seen in the past to solve this is to clean the project, confirm that the gradle properties is set to the correct version (which would be 0.6.+ atm), and then click the Gradle Sync button in the toolbar.

Comment: Actually I tried these options(clean build, rebuild, and sync). In my case there is no change in gradle. 

I agree that restart is not a solution! but haven't found the reason yet.

Comment: Did you confirm your build.gradle file is correct? Ie the gradle dependency version.
Syncing only really refreshes the property with the current build settings.

Comment: Yes, build.gradle is correct. It is working fine after restart. 

We use version control in team so we synchronize periodically whenever we upgrade at that I do sync.

Comment: Thanks Chris, Gradle Sync options is working! though there was no build.gradle file change.